# Update in Sqlite with fields from another row

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, database-performance

Is there any way of simplifying this update query in Sqlite?

```
update people set
phone = (select phone from people where id=2),
email = (select email from people where id=2)
where id=1;
```

The query obviously copies some fields from one person to other.

If this is done for a couple fields, this way seems very unefficient to me as it performs a lot of subqueries.

Any optimization?

Comment: I think something similar to this can be done in PostgreSQL:

`update people set (phone,email) =
(select phone,email from people where id=2)
where id=1`

wich does only use one subquery. But what about Sqlite?

Comment: The subqueries just retrieve a single value likely using an indexed column. Is there a performance problem really, or is this another case of premature optimization?

Comment: @laalto, nice appointment! I don't really know! Should I've spoken of prettier code or tinier code!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPDATE syntax does not allow looking up multiple values at once.

It might be possible to use REPLACE:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO people(id, phone, email, other, fields)
SELECT old.id, new.phone, new.email, old.other, old.fields
FROM people AS old,
     people AS new
WHERE old.id = 1
  AND new.id = 2
```

... but this would actuall delete the record before re-inserting it, which would be even worse.

The simplest way would be to use two commands:

```
SELECT phone, email FROM people WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE people SET phone = ?, email = ? WHERE ID = 1;
```